# How can we phrase multiple promotions from X to Y to Z

Tags: sentence-construction, vocabulary, sentence-structure

Jumping from X to Z do not show the progress and might be perceived as exaggeration. Received successive promotions from... or else is there any other structure can be used here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely to hear a native speaker use "through the ranks" here (from Oxford Dictionaries):

> [**rise through (or from) the ranks**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rise_through_(or_from)_the_ranks)
>   PHRASE
>
> **1** (of a privateor non-commissioned officer) receive a commission.
>
> > **1.1** Advance in an organisation by one's own efforts.
> >     *"he rose through the ranks to become a managing director"*

While the dictionary definition includes "to rise," it wouldn't sound unusual to me to hear "through the ranks" used without "to rise," for example:

> He was promoted through the ranks *[from clerk]* to managing director.

Equally, you could use just "through":

> [**through**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/through)
>   PREPOSITION & ADVERB
>
> **4** *North American [preposition]* Up to and including (a particular point
>   in an ordered sequence)
>   *"they will be in London from March 24 through May 7"*

The definition says "North American," but as a British English speaker it wouldn't sound out of place to me. For example:

> He was promoted from clerk through to managing director.

It's also possible to use a phrase of "to work" if you wanted to add some emphasis to the person having been promoted through (hard) work:

> [**work one's way up**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/work)
>
> Progress towards something better or ascend of series of ranks through hard
>   work.
>   *"she worked her way up to become a vice president"*

Comment: This is an excellent answer and thought me the phrase of "rise through (or from) the ranks". If you do not mind me asking, is there a possibility to insert a third variable here. Using above example: from clerk through assistant to managing director. How does it sound to you ?

Comment: @diemantiyanko: That sounds perfectly fine. You could use multiple intermediate roles: "from clerk through assistant and executive officer to managing director." You could use many for emphasis or if those roles have special significance, but using too many makes it sound unnatural.